# jsPanel displaying PHP output

Tags: php, jquery, jpanel

I'm using jsPanel to create a floating 'panel' window like so:

```
 $.jsPanel({
        headerTitle: 'Some title',
        content: '<p> Hello world! </p>'      
           })
```

This works great, but where I'm having trouble is that I want that 'content' to contain PHP data. For example:

```
     $.jsPanel({
        headerTitle: 'Some title',
        content: '<?php echo "Hello world!"; ?>'      
           })
```

This does not work. So what I have tried is:

```
         $.jsPanel({
        headerTitle: 'Some title',
        contentAjax: {url: 'helloworld.php'}
                   })
```

No luck. So after further googles, I found something similar:

```
   $.jsPanel({
        headerTitle: 'Some title',
        load: {url: 'helloworld.php'}
             })
```

... which didn't work either.

So I guess my questions are this -

- How can I get PHP code to output properly to a floating "jsPanel" window?
- Why does ajax/load do seemingly to same thing, and what's the difference here?

Comment: Have you tried storing the `php` content in a variable first? like `<?php $mData = "hello world!";?>`  and then `content: '<?php echo $mData; ?>'`. Also check the third example [here](http://v2.jspanel.de/documentation/optionLoad.html)

Answer (score 0):

Let's start with the easiest working example which uses **option.contentAjax**

```
$.jsPanel({
    headerTitle: 'Some title',
    contentAjax: 'test.php'
});
```

Now test.php (which is processed on the server) is required to output something useful in order to append it to the panel.

test.php:

```
<?php
    echo "<p style='text-align:center;'>Lorem ipsum dolor ...</p>";
?>
```

The more detailed example of the javascript would be:

```
$.jsPanel({
    headerTitle: 'Some title',
    contentAjax: {
        url: 'test.php',
        done: function( data, textStatus, jqXHR, panel ) {
            panel.content.append(data);
        }
    }
});
```

Always remember that php code is running on the server.

Your last code example does not work because there is no option.load in jsPanel. But you could use jQuery.load() like:

```
$.jsPanel({
    headerTitle: 'Some title',
    callback: function() {
        this.content.load('test.php');
    }
});
```

or:

```
$.jsPanel({
    headerTitle: 'Some title',
    content: function() {
        $(this).load('test.php');
    }
});
```

Hope I could help a bit ...